# Inserting timestamp to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert timestamp to my MySQL database using PHP. But there is shown an error off

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/e-exam/user.message.php on line 22

But

> Here line 22 is ':sent_at' => $timestamp

```
 $timestamp = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');

      //message sending
      $sql3 = "INSERT INTO message(title, content, sender_id, sent_at ) VALUES (:title, :content, :sender_id, :sent_at)";
      $stmt3 = $pdo->prepare($sql3);
      $stmt3->execute(array(
        ':title' => $_POST['title'],
        ':content' => $_POST['content'],
        ':email' => $_SESSION['active_user'],
        ':sent_at' => $timestamp
      ));
```

Please help me to solve this error

Comment: Check your INSERT query. Its not correct. (title, content, sender_id, sent_at) - Your are missing email here. Or :email is wrong. Depending on what you want to insert there. Anyway, fixing this should make it work.

Comment: Sorry, was forgot that.Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to insert the sent_at ( current time ) , there is easier way, by using NOW() at first you create the table.

the other way is by change the line into this

```
"INSERT INTO message(title, content, sender_id, sent_at ) VALUES (:title, :content, :sender_id, NOW())";
```

take a lot at **NOW()** in the query.

you can try the query

```
select NOW()
```

it will result something like this **2018-07-04 18:17:49**

in mysql you can use data type **datetime**